# Can I bottle room temperature beer with a beer gun from a pressurized Fermentasaurus or Fermzilla?

Tags: beer, bottling, temperature, fermenter

I am currently fermenting an IPA at room temperature in a Fermentasaurus. It has built up a nice bit of pressure which is carbonating my beer, GREAT! Nature: awesome.

Now I've been looking at better ways of bottling my beer. Normally I would add priming sugar and bottle condition it. However, I already have perfectly carbonated beer now, what a waste to start over!

Kegging is not within my budget at the moment, so that's out of the question for now.

Then I stumbled upon the Blichmann Beer Gun which looked like it might just do the trick. However, I can't seem to find anyone who has experience directly bottling from the Fermentasaurus / Fermzilla using a beer gun. Several shops sell the fermenter as a full kit including the beer gun so they must think it might work.

During my research I keep reading that the beer and bottles need to be of the same temperature.. which is great, but everybody has everything chilled in fridges. Unfortunately I don't have the luxury of throwing a complete Fermentasaurus in the fridge.

- Would it make sense at all to take the beer that's at room temperature and fill my bottles (I can chill those, as suggested) with a beer gun or will that be a total waste?
- It sounds like the high temperature will produce too much foam. Is that a real concern?
- Are there any other negatives to trying to use a beer gun on beer that is this warm and is not coming from a keg?
- Has anybody ever tried to bottle directly from the Fermentasaurus / Fermzilla using a beer gun?
- The other option is a Counterpressure Bottle Filler, but I expect the temperature to be a problem here as well, but is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If beer is "perfectly carbonated beer", then transferring it isn't a problem. What happen with "warm" beer is that it doesn't retain/absorb gas as a cold liquid. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law

Putting a keg at room temperature and purge it few time will lower the CO2 volume in liquid. Using it cold with pressure will add CO2 volume.

If you can pour a glass of well carbonated beer, then you can bottle it.

Using cold bottles helps to create less foam will using your beergun.

Comment: Thanks! I decided against it after reading loads more and asking at my brew shop if it would make any sense to buy a beer gun. They're not good salespeople, too honest. 